# Not rounded Container widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to rounded corners of Container widget (red background)

Snippet:

```
 new Stack(children: [
                          new ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                                Constants.ROUNDED_CORNER_RADIUS)),
                            child: new Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
                                    Constants.HALF_DEFAULT_MARGIN,
                                    Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
                                    Constants.HALF_DEFAULT_MARGIN),
                                height: 40.0,
                                width: 72.0,
                                color: Colors.red),
                ),
```

Result:

[image]

Why not rounded widget Container with red background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the **margin** has cut out where the ClipRRect will clip

It is clipping it but you can't see it because of the margin

You can use the borderRadius property in the decoration of the Container like this

```
Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
              width: 72,
              height: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
              ),
            ),
          )
```